# make a API in PHP which accept Request / response Zipped, gziped, deflate

Tags: php

I am working on API Development using PHP, so i need a function which look the request encoding and set the reponse based on encoding like "Zipped", "gziped", "deflate" etc, and output should be in JSON.

I am trying to use below code, but when run causing the error "This webpage is not available\n ERR_CONTENT_DECODING_FAILED"

So, please suggest any one how we can implement such thing.

```
function convertToHeaderEncoding($input, $encoding, $debug = 0)
{   
    $compressed_out = "";

    if($encoding == "gzip") 
    {       
        $compressed_out = gzencode($input);

        if($debug == 1)     
            echo 'Gzipd Output'."\n".'Before compression size '.strlen($output).' bytes'."\n".' After compression size '.strlen($compressed_out).' bytes';

        header("Content-Encoding: gzip");
        return $compressed_out;     
    }
    else    
        return $input;      
}
```

$arr = array("Key1"=>"I find this works well, save the snip below in your php/ directory then edit your prepend.php file and add a require statement that requires the compression.php file below. Once complete watch (tail -f) your php error log to see the results of compression in action. I find this works well, save the snip below in your php/ directory then edit your prepend.php file and add a require statement that requires the compression.php file below. Once complete watch (tail -f) your php error log to see the results of compression in action. I find this works well, save the snip below in your php/ directory then edit your prepend.php file and add a require statement that requires the compression.php file below. Once complete watch (tail -f) your php error log to see the results of compression in action");

```
$jsonString = json_encode($arr, true);

$output = convertToHeaderEncoding($jsonString, "gzip", 1);
echo $output;
```

Comment: Are you trying to reinvent the wheel? Why don't you use any ready to use frameworks/classes/etc.? Belive me that is the much more better way ;)

Comment: can you give me some URLs / sample for framework / classes

Comment: Look for slim framework for example then write a custom middleware to compress/gzip the Response object

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure whether your code can work that way. Try this solution:

```
// Turn on output buffering with the gzhandler
ob_start('ob_gzhandler');

// Output as normal
echo json_encode($data);
```